# Obtain jars from maven project

Tags: maven, tomcat, jar, jax-ws

I can guess this is a easy to answer question, here it goes.

I have seen tons of tutorials asking me to do this:

> - Go here http://jax-ws.java.net/.
> - Download JAX-WS RI distribution.
> - Unzip it and copy following JAX-WS dependencies to Tomcat library    folder “{$TOMCAT}/lib“.

But I don't see any jars, just a maven project which may install them in the first execution, maybe in .m2? Do I have to compile it to get the jars?

Some examples:

[Step "add necesary libraries to Tomcat" of this tutorial](https://memorynotfound.com/deploy-jaxws-application-tomcat-example/)

[Step 1 of this tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/9133/jax-ws-web-service-deployment-on-tomcat-server)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you will be able to find these dependencies in [maven central](https://search.maven.org/) or [MVNRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/)

You can find the JAX-WS RI details in the locations listed below:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-ri
- https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:jaxws-ri

Once you find the information in these places you can add the dependencies to your maven's pom.xml and you should be good

Comment: as the title says, I need the jars. I know how maven works, just asking if the steps are posible to follow.

Comment: I didn't find any binaries in the JAX-WS RI project [page](https://javaee.github.io/metro-jax-ws/). If pulling the jar files from a maven repository is not an option then you will need to build the project and get the binaries from there.